# What's the best way to send an object to a component with nested data using Vue?

Tags: vue.js

Let's say I have the following data:

```
data: function() {
     return {
        a: "hello",
        b: {
          title: this.a + " BOB"
        }
     }
}
```

When I pass this in a component, the this.a is undefined.

```
<component :pass-data="b"></component>
```

How do I send that nested property?

Answer (score 2):

When the `data` function is called, `this.a` is `undefined`, so the `b` data property is being initialized as `"undefined BOB"`. You're sending that property correctly to the child component.

You should either make `b` a computed property:

```
computed: {
  b() {
    return { title: this.a + ' BOB' };
  }
}
```

Or set the value of `b.title` after the `data` method has fired:

```
data() {
  return {
    a: "hello",
    b: {
      title: ''
    }
  }
},
created() {
  this.b.title = this.a + " BOB";
}
```

Or, as @Roy J mentioned, you can build the data object however you want to before returning in the `data` method:

```
data() {
  let a = "hello";

  return {
    a: a,
    b: {
      title: a + " BOB"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since `data` is a function, you can assemble the object there, rather than using `created`. It doesn't have to be a single statement returning an object literal.

Comment: @RoyJ Good suggestion. OP's example seems simplified so I'm not sure what their actual situation is / why they need to reference `this.a`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a computed property

```
data: function() {
     return {
        a: "hello",
        b: " BOB"
     },
  computed:{
    bComputed: function(){
       return this.a + this.b;
     } 
 }
}
```

and pass

`<component :pass-data="bComputed"></component>`

PS: Wasn't the `;` behind your " BOB" a problem for the compiler?